# Change histogram bars color

Tags: matplotlib

I'm plotting a histogram for a random distributions, is there a way to change the color of the bars without having to plot again ?

So instead of writing `my_subplot.hist(data, color='red')`, I would only need to write something like this : `my_subplot.set_color('red')`

Comment: You can grab the bars with `_, _, bars = ax.hist(np.random.randn(10000), color='crimson')`and then change the color: `for bar in bars: bar.set_color('turquoise')`.

Comment: That was very helpful thanks a lot !